# How to make circle on corners of box in flutter?

Tags: android, flutter, dart

I want to make a circle on each vertex of boxes(sqaure) and lines on each edge. How can I achieve that in flutter?

I have used Box Decoration to make those boxes. Below is the code:

```
        GridView.builder(
          itemCount: 20,
          itemBuilder: (context, index) =>
              GestureDetector(
                  onTap: (),
                  child: Container(
                      decoration: BoxDecoration(
                          color: Colors.green, shape: BoxShape.rectangle),
                          color: Colors.red, shape: BoxShape.circle);
          gridDelegate: SliverGridDelegateWithFixedCrossAxisCount(
            crossAxisCount: 4,
            mainAxisSpacing: 2,
            crossAxisSpacing: 2,
          ),
```

Please suggest how can I achieve this.

Below is expected for circle + I want to add lines on edges too : [image]

and this is my output:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[image]

Here is the full solution (`h` donates Horizontal, and `v` Vertical)

```
double _hPadding = 72, _vPadding = 20, _dotSize = 20;
int _hBox = 3, _vBox = 4;

@override
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
  return Scaffold(
    appBar: AppBar(),
    body: Stack(
      children: <Widget>[
        Padding(
          padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: _hPadding, vertical: _vPadding),
          child: _buildBoxLayout(),
        ),
        Padding(
          padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: _hPadding - _dotSize / 2, vertical: _vPadding - _dotSize / 2),
          child: _buildDotLayout(),
        ),
      ],
    ),
  );
}

Widget _buildBoxLayout() {
  return GridView.builder(
    itemCount: _hBox * _vBox,
    itemBuilder: (context, index) => Container(color: Colors.grey[((index % 2) + 2) * 100]),
    gridDelegate: SliverGridDelegateWithFixedCrossAxisCount(crossAxisCount: _hBox),
  );
}

Widget _buildDotLayout() {
  double spacing = (MediaQuery.of(context).size.width - _hPadding * 2 - _hBox * _dotSize) / _hBox;
  return GridView.builder(
    itemCount: (_hBox + 1) * (_vBox + 1),
    itemBuilder: (context, index) => Container(decoration: BoxDecoration(shape: BoxShape.circle, color: Colors.grey[700])),
    gridDelegate: SliverGridDelegateWithFixedCrossAxisCount(
      crossAxisCount: _hBox + 1,
      crossAxisSpacing: spacing,
      mainAxisSpacing: spacing
    ),
  );
}
```

Comment: Hey thanks haa , can you just tell me how can I have edges all over also ..

Comment: Sorry I didn't get that. Can you show the screenshot of what you are asking.

Comment: This is what I am asking to do so actually I want to have edges in different color and to be shown only when i click between the 2 circles so for that first I need to have edged all over. https://drive.google.com/file/d/16Vkty5jc3AY9EnpD_eMLdIBIi6t36V1d/view?usp=sharing

Comment: I am getting red quickly lines over MediaQuery.of(context) saying 'undefined name context.' 
N how would I call this whole class on clicking a button because I want to have this grid on clicking a button but I can't have this.??

Comment: @Prianca For edges you can easily make another layout widget and put it in `Stack` as last item just like I did `_buildBoxLayout` and `_buildDotLayout`. And for the error part, I think you must be using `StatelessWidget`, if so, make sure to use `StatefulWidget`, and if you are already using `StatefulWidget`, please share a screenshot of your IDE showing error.

Comment: Hey no error there now and I want to know this: 
 double spacing = (MediaQuery.of(context).size.width - _hPadding * 2 - _hBox * _dotSize) / _hBox;

Comment: I mean what logic ? Please tell

Comment: It is tough to make you understand without pointing to relevant part of the screenshot, well the story is you don't have control over `width` and `height` of `GridView` `children`, you need to make things using `childAspectRatio` (which is `1` by default), `crossAxisSpacing` and `mainAxisSpacing`. So, first we tell how wide we want our box to be, depending on it we find out remaining space and using that space we find out how much `crossAxisSpacing` we need. Same thing goes for `mainAxisSpacing`. Hope you got bit of the essence.